# mouse events to affect only one element of the secondary class (without using id) - jquery

Tags: class, mouseevent, jquery

I have multiple divs with `class="aaa"` - each contains some text with `class="bbb"`.

When I mouseenter one div, I need to change div's background and color of the text which is inside of that div. I need to achieve this *without using individual ids* (because there are many divs).

Right now I only know how to achieve the 1st part, but I don't know the 2nd:

```
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#555555');
    $('.bbb').css('color', 'white');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#cccccc');
    $('.bbb').css('color', 'black');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9XbKr/

How this can be achieved in the most practical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most practical way, but it should work.

```
$('.aaa').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#555555');
    $(this).find(".bbb").css('color', 'white');
});
$('.aaa').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).css('background', '#cccccc');
    $(this).find(".bbb").css('color', 'black');
});
```

You can use `.children()` instead of `.find()` if the elements with class `.bbb` are direct descendants of those with class `.aaa`.

Answer (score 0):

[SEE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oHUXIxi/7/edit)

jQuery

```
$(document).on({

    mouseenter: function () {

        $(this).addClass("green");

    },
    mouseleave: function () {

        $(this).removeClass("green");
    }

}, ".aaa");
```

CSS

```
.red {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
 }

 .green{
     background-color: green; 
 }
```